# generic case class to json using writter

Tags: json, scala, serialization

I am trying to convert this model to Json but I always got the error "No apply function found matching unapply parameters".

I tried to implement two different writters for doing this but both do not work.

Here is my model:

```
case class Page[T](
    var data: List[T],
    var previous: String,
    var next: String,
    var totalPageCount: Int)(implicit val tWrites: Writes[T])

object Page {

    // Both Writters generate an "No apply function found matching unapply parameters" error
    implicit val pageWrites = Json.writes[Page[_]]

    implicit def pageWriter[T]: Writes[Page[T]] = new Writes[Page[T]] {
        def writes(o: Page[T]): JsValue = {
            implicit val tWrites = o.tWrites
            val writes = Json.writes[Page[T]]
            writes.writes(o)
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone has a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this were possible, the syntax would probably look something like this:

```
implicit def pageWrites[T: Writes]: Writes[Page[T]] = Json.writes[Page[T]]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with JSON Inception (the macro that's behind `Json.writes`), so you'll need to use the standard longhand:

```
implicit def pageWrites[T: Writes]: Writes[Page[T]] = (
  (__ \ 'data).write[List[T]] and
  (__ \ 'previous).write[String] and
  (__ \ 'next).write[String] and
  (__ \ 'totalPageCount).write[Int]
)(unlift(Page.unapply[T]))
```

As a side note, it's probably a good idea to remove concerns about serialization from your model code—you can just drop the implicit `Writes` argument and use the `pageWrites` given here.

Comment: This work fine but I need to add a listWrites to serialize the generic List[T] type. Therefore I added this :
    implicit def listWrites[T](implicit fmt: Writes[T]): Writes[List[T]] = new Writes[List[T]] {
        def writes(ts: List[T]) = JsArray(ts.map(t => Json.toJson(t)(fmt)))
    }

but now I am getting a "MatchError: null" message on this listWrites when excuting my project.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a writer for `List[T]`—Play will provide that for you.

Comment: If I do not add it I get this error on List[T]: "No Json deserializer found for type java.util.List[T]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type."

Comment: That's because `java.util.List` is different from Scala's `List`. Can you convert to the Scala list in your case class?

Comment: Alright I did not see it was not the same List object. Not sure I can convert to the Scala one. It is not possible to write a generic writer for java.util.List[T] type ?

Comment: It is, but in most cases it's a much better idea to convert your Java collections to Scala as early as possible.

Comment: Ok then I am going to do this. What is the best way to do this ? Many different solutions are presented in stackoverflow question 674713. And where should I do it ? In my case class ?

Comment: You should keep that kind of logic out of case classes whenever possible. Probably deserves a new question.